# Instant AR framework Apple Mach-O Linker Errors

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios6, linker-errors

I've followed this tutorial to try implement the instant AR framework into my Xcode project: http://instantar.org/archive/181

But when I try to build it, I get about 200 Apple Mach-O Linker Errors, i've tried to set the 'Build for current architecture only' to No but it still fails to compile.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: have you changed this following?please check
appdelegate extension and main file extension .mm
arm7 and arm7s

Comment: if you have used any static library please run your code on device

Comment: Yes i've changed both those files to .mm but i'm not sure what you mean with armv7 and armv7s?

Comment: check with your project summary page .build architecture is arm7 and arm7s.some library need this architecture

Comment: ok i've checked that - still not building

Comment: r u take build on device or stimulator.

Comment: its set to build on device

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40911/discussion-between-muthu-ram-and-user1083813)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please re add library file in your project folder and check with it in compile resource .

Answer (score 0):

Check Compile resource all .m files are added are not if not added then add   try it